# Inheritance and Namespaces in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Image.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

using namespace math;

namespace imaging
{
    class Image: public Array
    {
        public:
            Image();
    };
}
```

Array.h

```
namespace math
{

    template <typename T>
    class Array
    {
        protected:
            T * buffer;
            unsigned int width, height;
        public:
            Array(unsigned int w, unsigned int h);
    };
}
```

and Array.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace math
{
    Array::Array(unsigned int w, unsigned int h)
    {
        this->width = w;
        this->height = h;
    }
}
```

I have these errors:
Image.h:12:2: error: expected class-name before `{` token

```
{
```

^
In file included from Image.cpp:1:0:
Image.h:12:2: error: expected class-name before `{` token

```
{
```

^
Array.cpp:8:2: error: invalid use of template-name `math::Array` without an argument list
  `Array::Array(unsigned int w, unsigned int h)`

Any help for this??? Thnx

Comment: You'll have to template-ize `class Image` . `template <typename T>
    class Image: public Array<T> { }`

Comment: Small comment about names: array is known as the basic 1D collection of entries in C and C++.  in C++ there is also `std::array`, so naming an 2D-array `Array` maybe okay in the problem domain, but is confusing in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put you definition of the `Array` constructor in the header, with the correct syntax for a template:

```
namespace math
{
    template<typename T>
    Array::Array(unsigned int w, unsigned int h)
    {
        this->width = w;
        this->height = h;
    }
}
```

An important rule of thumb is that you should not cannot define functions for `template` classes in source files. (You can in certain circumstances but do regard that as the exception rather than the rule.)

Answer (score 0):

**Without the `<>`, `Array` is assumed as a non-template class which is not the case here, thus resulting into the error.**

You have a problem here:

```
namespace imaging
{
    class Image: public Array
```

it should be

```
namespace imaging
{
   template <typename T>
   class Image: public Array<T>
```

Comment: thank u very much! so for class Image how main program can see?? using typedefs??